# How to compare a string* and const char* in an if statement?

Tags: c++

I am trying to compare a `string*` to a `const char*` in an `if` statement. The string pointer is apart of a class called `HashNode` (a node for a hash table implemented with Linear Probing). I am trying to set the node's status to `"never used"`, `"tombstone"`, or `"occupied"`. My code, which is throwing errors, is as follows:

```
while (table[slot]->status != "never used"){
    // if the node is found, return true
    if(table[slot]->word == word) return true ;
    // increment index and wrap back around the table
    slot = (slot + 1) % TableSlots ;
}
```

My HashNode class is defined as:

```
class HashNode{
public:
    string *word ;
    const char *status ;

    // Basic constructor for a node
    HashNode(string word, string status) {
        // this keyword references the key and word variables which belong to the class
        this->word = &word ;
        this->status = status ;
    }
} ;
```

I have changed the `status` declaration in `HashNode` to `const char*` to try and remove this error, but how would I get around the following:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression
('std::__1::string *' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>,
allocator<char> > *') and 'std::__1::string' (aka 'basic_string<char,
char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >'))
if(table[slot]->word == word) return true ;
```

Comment: The error message is clear: A pointer to a string cannot be compared to a string. (Dereference the pointer.) A bigger problem is that your code will either crash or at least cause lots of errors in `valgrind`. The root cause is that your constructor gets a `string` argument by value (which ends up being a local variable on the constructor’s stack), takes a pointer to that local variable and stores it in the class instance’s `word` field. Once the constructor finishes, it destroys the local variable to which `word` is now pointing. Once other code dereferences `word`, the world will explode.

Comment: The `word` member of `HashNode` does not need to be a pointer.     Remove the asterisk (i.e. declare the member as `std::string word`) and change the line in the constructor `this->word = &word` (which produces a dangling reference so causes undefined behaviour when the word member is dereferenced after the constructor completes) to `this->word = word`.

Comment: `this->word = &word ;` -- If this is just an oversight, ok.  But if this code was written purposefully, then I always wonder why so many want to implement non-trivial data structures in C++ without a firm grasp of the simple basics of the language.   Implementing such structures requires firm knowledge of basic C++.  This is obviously wrong, due to what was already stated in the previous comment.  Also, the issue has nothing to do with `string`, as even a simple `int` would have the same issue of the dangling reference.

Comment: why do you use `std::string` and `const char*` in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

The error is complaining about comparing a pointer to a nonpointer.
Deference the pointer first:

```
if(*(table[slot]->word) == word) return true ;
```

Comment: This isn't actually the cause of the error message seen by the OP.   And it will cause another one.

Comment: Maybe I’d also add: `valgrind` is your friend. Because `this->word = &word` definitely won’t stay unpunished after the constructor exits and something dereferences `word` (the instance field), still pointing at `word` (the no-longer-alive local variable).

Comment: Are you sure @Peter? The error says "error: invalid operands to binary expression" then "string*" and "string"

Comment: It's a problem, but the root problem is the use of `string *` in the first place. Sometimes fixing the compiler error isn't the solution. The solution comes from answering, "Why am I getting a compiler error in the first place?" Note to those who come in the future, a pointer to a `string` or a C++ library container is very often wrong. And even when it's right, you have to be extra careful.

Comment: My previous comment was made when your code sample read `while (*(table[slot]->status) != "never used"){` and before you edited it to `if(*(table[slot]->word) == word) return true ;`.   With the edit, your code simply has undefined behaviour.